# How to Order an out of sequence sequence

Tags: c#, linq

Consider this list of elements which has three properties, Value and Sequence Number and Group:

```
Value    Sequence Number   Group   

Header,       1,           null
Invoice,      2,           1
Invoice Line, 3,           1
Trailer,      4,           null
```

The goal is only to sort by the sequence number. The value is irrelevant.

In the above, the obvious answer is to order by sequence number.

However, elements can repeat:

```
Header,     1,   null
InvoiceA,   2,   1
Line Item,  3,   1
InvoiceB,   2,   2
Line Item,  3,   2
Trailer,  4,   null
```

The above is the desired sequence.  What Linq statement will produce the above?

Sorting by Sequence no longer works.  Sorting by Group, then Sequence does not work.

The application of this is in EDI where the order of the data is significant.

Comment: So you're saying that if the group is null, order just by sequence - presumably there's no other item with that sequence number in that case? Otherwise, order by group then sequence? I have to say, it's a pretty odd data model. Do you have any control over it?

Comment: Yes, I can change the data model.  The only thing I can't change is the order that it must come out in.

Comment: Hmm looks like we are forced to guess here. My guess: Order by Group then by Sequence with null counting as smaller than 0. Would explain both cases...

Comment: @DrKoch: No, because that way X, 4, null would come before X, 2, 1.

Comment: @DrKoch If you did that then in the second case {x,4,null} would be second, not last.

Comment: @DrKoch If null is smaller than zero, then the final element would not come out last.

Comment: @GregGum: So what is the group meant to represent? Why is it sometimes null and sometimes not? Basically, if you have a sort order which is hard to explain in words - which it looks like it is, here - it's bound to be hard to implement.

Comment: Yes, just noticed that. So: What are the rules?

Comment: The group only represents related records that must stay in order.  So group one comes before group two, etc.

Comment: It's sometimes null because it does not related to a group (such as header and trailer records.)

Comment: Where would {X, 2, null} or {X, 3, null} go in that order?

Comment: You'd make your live a million times easier by just ensuring that the header always had a group number of `0` and the trailer always had a group number of `int.MaxValue` (and that no other items used either of those numbers) or something like that, so you could just order by group number then by sequence number.

Comment: @juharr, Repeating elements would not have a null group.  I revised the example.

Comment: @Servy, I will try that as well.

Comment: Sort by Value, then Sequence. `Sorting by Sequence no longer works. Sorting by Group, then Sequence does not work.` <-- please describe "does not work"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the first "trick" here is that you want all items with a `null` group to be separate groups, rather than having all `null` items combined into a single group.

This is actually fairly easy.  We can just create an `IEqualityComparer` that compares items based on some other comparer, but that always considers two `null` items to be different, instead of being the same (typically two `null` items would be considered "equal").

```
public class SeparateNullComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private IEqualityComparer<T> comparer;
    public SeparateNullComparer(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        this.comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;
        return comparer.Equals(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return comparer.GetHashCode(obj);
    }
}
```

We can now group the items using this comparer so that all non-null items will be grouped together, whereas all of the `null` items will have their own groups.

Now how do we order the groups?  We need to order these groups based on their sequence numbers, but we have a sequence of them, not just one, so we need a way of comparing two sequences to see which sequence comes first.  We do this by checking the first item in each sequence, and then continually checking the next until one comes first or one ends and the other doesn't:

```
public class SequenceComparer<T> : IComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    private IComparer<T> comparer;
    public SequenceComparer(IComparer<T> compareer = null)
    {
        this.comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
    }

    public int Compare(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        using (var first = x.GetEnumerator())
        using (var second = x.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var firstHasMore = first.MoveNext();
                var secondHasMore = second.MoveNext();
                if (!firstHasMore && !secondHasMore)
                    return 0;
                var lengthComparison = firstHasMore.CompareTo(secondHasMore);
                if (lengthComparison != 0)
                    return lengthComparison;
                var nextComparison = comparer.Compare(first.Current, second.Current);
                if (nextComparison != 0)
                    return nextComparison;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Combine that with flattening all of the groups back out when we're done, and we just need to put it all together:

```
var query = data.GroupBy(item => item.Group, new SeparateNullComparer<int?>())
    .Select(group => group.OrderBy(item => item.SequenceNumber)
        .ToList())
    .OrderBy(group => group, new SequenceComparer<Foo>())
    .ThenBy(group => group.First().Group)
    .SelectMany(x => x);
```

You can also rely on the fact that `GroupBy` maintains the original order of items within groups, allowing you to order the data by `SequenceNumber` before grouping, instead of after.  It'll do basically the same thing.  It turns out to be a prettier query, but you just need to "know" that `GroupBy` maintains the proper ordering:

```
var query = data.OrderBy(item => item.SequenceNumber)
    .GroupBy(item => item.Group, new SeparateNullComparer<int?>())
    .OrderBy(group => group, new SequenceComparer<Foo>())
    .ThenBy(group => group.Key)
    .SelectMany(x => x);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have to be a linq query, you could write a single comparer that looks like this:

```
public class ValSeqGroupComparer : IComparer<ValSeqGroup>
{
    public int Compare(ValSeqGroup x, ValSeqGroup y)
    {
        if (x == y) return 0;

        // If only one has a group or there is no group in either
        if (x.Group.HasValue ^ y.Group.HasValue || !x.Group.HasValue)
            return x.Seq.CompareTo(y.Seq);

        if (x.Group.Value != y.Group.Value)
            return x.Group.Value.CompareTo(y.Group.Value);

        return x.Seq.CompareTo(y.Seq);
    }
}
```

Then using it like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void One()
{
    List<ValSeqGroup> items = new List<ValSeqGroup>()
    {
        new ValSeqGroup("x", 1, null),
        new ValSeqGroup("x", 4, null),
        new ValSeqGroup("x", 2, 1),
        new ValSeqGroup("x", 2, 2),
        new ValSeqGroup("x", 3, 1),
        new ValSeqGroup("x", 3, 2)
    };

    items.Sort(new ValSeqGroupComparer());

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", item.Value, item.Seq,item.Group);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by sorting the elements by Sequence Number (`OrderBy(x => x.SequenceNumber)`).

After that you can sort elements with exising group number (`.Where(x => x.Group != null).OrderBy(x => x.Group)`)

In the end you have to insert null elements in list at the corresponding index.

```
var elements = new List<Element>
{
    new Element{SequenceNumber = 1, Group = null}, new Element{SequenceNumber = 4, Group = null},new Element{SequenceNumber = 3, Group = 1},new Element{SequenceNumber = 3, Group = 3}, new Element{SequenceNumber = 3, Group = 2},new Element{SequenceNumber = 2, Group = 3},new Element{SequenceNumber = 2, Group = 1},new Element{SequenceNumber = 2, Group = 2}       
};

// first sort
var sortedElements = elements.OrderBy(x => x.SequenceNumber).ToList();

// save null elements
var elementsWithNull = sortedElements
    .Where(x => x.Group == null).ToList();

// group sorting
sortedElements = sortedElements
    .Where(x => x.Group != null)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Group).ToList();

// insert elements with null in sorted list
foreach (var element in elementsWithNull)
{
    var firstIndexOfSequence = 0;
    for (firstIndexOfSequence = 0;firstIndexOfSequence < sortedElements.Count && sortedElements[firstIndexOfSequence].SequenceNumber >= element.SequenceNumber; firstIndexOfSequence++)
    {
        // just to get index of the element with null group to know where to insert
    }

    sortedElements.Insert(firstIndexOfSequence, element);
}
```